# I get This site can’t be reached error when I install my .Net Core 5 Web Api on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I get This site can’t be reached error when I install my .Net Core 5 Web Api on IIS.

This is my config:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\{myappname}.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
```

The dll works when I use dotnet cli, but it doesn't work in IIS.
Any thoughts?

---

The error:
[image]

My AppPool uses "No Managed Code".
My Bindings are both http (port 80) and https (port 443).

Comment: `This site can’t be reached error` Please share the detailed error page, and please share site bindings, so that we can help troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: @FeiHan Thank you for your response. I edited the question with the required details. Please take a look at it again.

Comment: if possible, please share your site bindings.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @FeiHan.  My binding uses both http (80) and https (443). I used each of the bindings merely as well, but it didn't work. The AppPool also uses "No Managed Code".